# Отсортировать массив по названию страны и по названию города (если страны равны) в порядке возрастания

Tags: javascript

```
function sortCitiesArray(arr) {
  let newArr = [];
  newArr[0] = arr[0];
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, current, i) {
    if (current.country <= newArr[0].country) {
      newArr.unshift(current);
    }
    newArr.reduce(function(prev, current) {
      if (current.country > arr[i].country) {
        newArr.splice(i - 1, 0, current);

      }
      return newArr;
    })
    return newArr;
  })
}
```

Можно использовать только .map или .reduce

```
 *    [
 *      { country: 'Russia',  city: 'Moscow' },
 *      { country: 'Belarus', city: 'Minsk' },
 *      { country: 'Poland',  city: 'Warsaw' },
 *      { country: 'Russia',  city: 'Saint Petersburg' },
 *      { country: 'Poland',  city: 'Krakow' },
 *      { country: 'Belarus', city: 'Brest' }
 *    ]  
 *                      =>
 *    [
 *      { country: 'Belarus', city: 'Brest' },
 *      { country: 'Belarus', city: 'Minsk' },
 *      { country: 'Poland',  city: 'Krakow' },
 *      { country: 'Poland',  city: 'Warsaw' },
 *      { country: 'Russia',  city: 'Moscow' },
 *      { country: 'Russia',  city: 'Saint Petersburg' }
```

Comment: и  в чем проблема с твоим кодом? ну кроме того, что ты в своей функции сразу исключение кидаешь

Comment: исключение убрал, проблема в том что не правильно сортирует

Comment: почему неправильно? пример приведенный в конце вопроса - это как должно быть? или это как твоя функция возвращает?

Comment: почему бы не использовать просто функцию sort?

Comment: это так должно быть

Comment: можно применять только map и reduce

Comment: Для сортировки не применять метод сортировки... Что за фетиш такой? :)